# Was Jussie Smollett framed by Chicago Police?

Tags: politics, police

Based on a [petition on change.org](https://www.change.org/p/daniel-webb-we-demand-special-prosecutor-daniel-webb-drop-all-criminal-charges-against-jussie-smollett) there is a lot of information about Jussie.   I never heard this information until recently.   Is any of the things to pointing to him being innocent "true" or even maybe true.   (I am not concerned about the cherry picked information that certain people might be "corrupt" based on other cases/things.   Looking at just the facts on Jussie.  Could he have been framed?)

Comment: What do you think a good answer would look like? We aren't interested in people's *opinions* of what a court might decide. We don't want guesses based on limited evidence. A court has not yet made a verdict. This seems unanswerable to me.

Answer (score 4):

**Jussie Smollett's double jeopardy claim tossed out by judge**

It is too early to say, but at this moment Jussie Smollett is claiming double Jeopardy, which is not the same thing as claiming to have been framed by Chicago police.

[Fox News](https://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/jussie-smollett-double-jeopardy-claim-tossed-out-judge)

> Jussie Smollett took another hit in court on Friday when a judge shot down the actor's attempt to have the criminal charges against him dropped, telling Smollett that the new charges against him do not violate his right against double jeopardy, being charged twice for the same crime.

**Was Jussie Smollett framed by Chicago Police?**

Claims from third parties that are not even remotely connected to the case cannot truly be taken seriously, and the claim that he was framed by Chicago police would really need to come from Jussie Smollett himself, unless there is extraordinary evidence that he is being gagged, and thus cannot speak for himself.

Having looked through the Wikipedia pages connected to the case ([Jussie Smollett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussie_Smollett) and [Alleged assault of Jussie Smollett)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alleged_assault_of_Jussie_Smollett) as well as a couple of news articles including the Fox news report I provided, I can find no evidence that Jussie Smollett is claiming that he was framed by Chicago police.

**Is any of the things to pointing to him being innocent "true" or even maybe true.**

It would be unfair to comment on this particular statement prior to the trial, so I will stick with responding to your highlighted question only.

Comment: I find two parts of this argument troublesome: (i) There may be good reasons for Smollett to be unaware of the conspiracy or to avoid publicly promoting it. (ii) We can't tell if you have done a thorough search.